# tool to canonicalize many (100x) horrible apache httpd www.mysite.com.conf configuration files

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I have inherited some servers which have many virtual hosts that have been "organically" developed over the years. Unfortunately they are awful to the eye, so bad, I cannot look at them.

Hence I am looking for a tool that will read in many hundreds of www.mystupidsite.com.conf files and return similarly working versions, with all the default redundancies and cruft stripped out.

I suspect it might be difficult because correctness would depend on other modules loaded, however given that there are many ancient apache shops about I can only hope.

Edit:

ive noticed that webmin provides a web interface to manage httpd.conf files, so I am going to look into how their perl modules handle parsing the files to some canonical state.

Comment: If you provided a sample of what needed changing, we might be able to help you, but with that, I'm afraid there's not much I can suggest.  My best guess would just be a lot of fun piping through `sed` and `grep`.